FCM-Django Push Notification Stopped Working After Recent Changes
I am using the FCM-Django module "fcm-django==1.0.14" to send push notifications to a mobile app built with Flutter. Previously, I used this code, and it worked fine.
def sendnotificationall(message, title, regis_id=None):
    try:
        if regis_id is None:
            devices = FCMDevice.objects.all()
        else:
            devices = regis_id
        dev = devices.send_message(Msg(notification=Notifi(title=title, body=message)))
        return "success"
    except:
        return "no device found"

However, when I checked it again recently, the code stopped working. Interestingly, when I sent notifications to individual instances, it started working correctly.
def sendnotificationall(message, title, regis_id=None):
    try:
        if regis_id is None:
            devices = FCMDevice.objects.all()
        else:
            devices = regis_id
        
        for device in devices:
            device.send_message(Msg(notification=Notifi(title=title, body=message)))
        return "success"
    except:
        return "no device found"

Can anyone explain what changes have been made to FCM-Django, or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Since firebase push notification update their API and the previous settings of django-push-notification won't works after June/24 if I am not wrong, Go to https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications/blob/master/docs/FCM.rst to update the api
